# Extracting URLs with elem.absUrl

Tags: java, parsing, networking, jsoup, web-crawler

I have a program all what I need it to do is to extract URLs from a text file and saves them into another text file. The code calls ExtractHTML2.getURL2(url,input); which is simply extract the HTML code for a given link (which works correctly & no need to include its code here).

**EDIT:** The code parse number of pages, on each page, it save its html code in text file, then parse this text file, to extract 10 links.

Now, the following code suppose to parse the extracted HTML code and extract the URLs. This does not work with me. It does not extract any thing.

**CODE EDITED:**

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import java.io.*;


public class ExtractLinks2 {

    public static void getLinks2(String url, int pages) throws IOException {
    {   
        Document doc;
        Element link; 
        String elementLink=null; 
        int linkId=1; //represent the Id of the href tag inside the HTML code

        //The file that contains the extracted HTML code for the web page. 
        File input = new File
         ("extracted.txt");

        //To write the extracted links
        FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter
         ("links.txt");

        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);

        // Loop to traverse the pages
           for (int z=1; z<=pages; z++) 
           {
               /*get the HTML code for that page and save 
                 it in input (extracted.txt)*/
               ExtractHTML2.getURL2(url, input);

               //Using parse function from JSoup library
               doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8");

               //Loop for 10 times to extract 10 links per page
               for(int e=1; e<=10; e++) 
               {
                 link = doc.getElementById("link-"+linkId); //the href tag Id
                 System.out.println("This is link no."+linkId);
                 elementLink=link.absUrl("href"); 
                  //write the extracted link to text file
                        out.write(elementLink);
                 out.write(","); //add a comma
                 linkId++; 
                } //end for loop

               linkId=1; //reset the linkId
            }//end for loop

        out.close();            
        } //end the getLinks function
    } //end IOExceptions


    } //end ExtractDNs class
```

As I said, my program does not extract the URLs. I have doubt in my syntax for Jsoup.parse. Reference to: http://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/load-document-from-file  there is optional third argument that I ignored it as I think it is not needed in my case. I need to extract from text file not html page.

My program is able to extract the href tag text if I typed: eURL =elem.text(); but I don’t need the text, I need the URL itself, e.g: If I have the following:

```
<a id="link-1" class="yschttl spt" href="/r/_ylt=A7x9QXi_UOlPrmgAYKpLBQx.;
_ylu=X3oDMTBzcG12Mm9lBHNlYwNzcgRwb3MDMTEEY29sbwNpcmQEdnRpZAM-/SIG=1329l4otf/
EXP=1340719423/**http%3a//www.which.co.uk/technology/computing/guides/how-to-buy
-the-best-laptop/" data-bk="5040.1">How to <b>buy</b> the best <b>laptop</b> 
- <b>Laptop</b> <wbr />reviews - Computing ...</a>
```

I only need "www.which.co.uk" or even better "which.co.uk" if there is a way to do that.

Why the above program does not extract URLs and how to correct the problem ?

Comment: does `elem.attr("href");` gives you the `/r/_ylt=A7x9QXi_UOlPrmgAYKpLBQx.;
_ylu=X3oDMTBzcG12Mm9lBHNlYwNzcgRwb3MDMTEEY29sbwNpcmQEdnRpZAM-/SIG=1329l4otf/
EXP=1340719423/**http%3a//www.which.co.uk/technology/computing/guides/how-to-buy
-the-best-laptop/` value ? also , what value does the `elem.absUrl("href")` gives you ?

Comment: No. It does not extract any thin. Empty string. But you can say the program is not stable. It could extract the links as in my example:"www.which.co.uk", and once later extracted the whole "/r/_ylt=A7x9QXi_UOlPrmgAYKpLBQx.; _ylu=X3oDMTBzcG12Mm9lBHNlYwNzcgRwb3MDMTEEY29sbwNpcmQEdnRpZAM-/SIG=1329l4otf/ EXP=1340719423/**http%3a//www.which.co.uk/technology/computing/guides/how-to-buy -the-best-laptop/".. But currently, with the Edited code that I posted, it does not extract anything. Note that, I have several pages, and 10 links in each. I clarified this in the EDIT.

Comment: try iterating like this `Elements links = content.getElementsByTag("a");
for (Element link : links) {....` look here http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/dom-navilink-1gation

Comment: @Daniel: Your link does not open with me. If you mean this: http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/dom-navigation I did this: Elements links = content.getElementsByTag("a"); But eclipse showing me type mismatch error. Also, what does for (Element link : links) ? haven't typed for loop in this way before.

Comment: @Daniel: I added Integer.toString(linkId) as the element id supposed to be a string, and I was adding int. So, I changed one line: link = doc.getElementById("link-" + Integer.toString(linkId)); It works now, but the program have worked several times before and stops again. If this really solved the problem, I will post solution.

Comment: I meant try : `Elements links = doc.getElementsByTag("a");
for (Element link : links) {
  String linkHref = link.attr("href");
  String linkAbsHref = link.absUrl("href");
}` About the loop, look here http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/flow/loops/foreach.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in this line:

```
link = doc.getElementById("link-"+linkId);
```

It should be:

```
link = doc.getElementById("link-" + Integer.toString(linkId));
```

Since `linkId` is integer, and `getElementById` takes string as parameter. So, I had to convert the Id to int first, so the input for the `getElementById` becomes in the form: link-1, link-2, etc.